# Symfony: Strings containing only numbers persist as numbers, fail queries

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, odm

I'm using Symfony and Mongo. I have documents for each of my mongo collections. In the documents I defined all fields to be strings, even though some of them typically contain numerical values.

I perform searches in these collections and filter them like this:

```
private function like($paramValue) {
    return new \MongoRegex("/.*" . FilterHelper::castValue(FilterType::INT, $paramValue) . ".*/ix");
}
...
$qb->field('articleId')->equals( $this->like($params['articleCode']) );
```

However, values are persisted as numbers in mongo, `"article_id": NumberInt(197568)`. The document is written like this:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\String(name="article_id")
 */
protected $articleId;
```

Naturally, queries fail because the type is not the expected. How can I fix this? I can't assume `$articleId` is a number.

Answer (score 0):

Did you thought about [strval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php) php function?

```
$qb->field('articleId')->equals( $this->like(strval($params['articleCode'])) );
```

Of course you should apply `strval` before pass it along `like()` function and verify the returned value

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Strval returns the string value, but mongo still contains numerical values and the filter still fails.

Comment: So use intval() function. Maybe I understood the opposite :)

Comment: Well, that will work most of the time, but the problem is how Mongo assumes number type for numerical strings, but string type for non numerical strings, which sometimes occur...